# Insecure Transport: Database in fortify Scan

Tags: .net, sql-server, fortify

I have got a issue in the fortify scan which is under the category **Insecure Transport: Database** . The issue is pointing to the connection string in config files. The application I am working is using VB.net and SQL Server and I am using windows authentication to connect to the DB.  I have done some searching on this and found the description of the issue in the link below. How I can solve this issue? Did anyone came across similar issue on FOD scan? Thanks in advance.

https://vulncat.fortify.com/en/detail?id=desc.config.dotnet.insecure_transport_database

**[Edit]** I got a clue that I need to add something like Encrypt = Yes in connection string. Whats is this? and what all changes I should do if this is what to be done.

Comment: SQL Server connections will be encrypted without the client explicitly requesting encryption if the force encryption is configured on the server. The client can also request encryption to ensure the connection is encrypted if not forced by the server and optionally opt in to not trust the server certificate for additional security. See [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: thanks for the reply. So if I force encryption in SQL server that will work same as passing encrypted=yes from client.

Comment: Encryption will occur without specifying Encrypt=True when forced on the server but a a self-signed cert if one is not provisioned on the server. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax) for more info.

Comment: How to achieve this in mysql connection str ?